# which types of noises occur in the binary images

Tags: image, image-processing, filtering, noise

which types of noises can occur in binary(black and white) image. can gaussian and speckel noise model is also for binary images (along with gray scale).If yes then how to apply this, as after applying the gaussian noise the image is no more binary,and it converted to gray scale.

Comment: all types can occur, the leader is often quantization noise.or else noise introduced by the dither mechanism.

Comment: Not sure if you want to apply noise or remove noise. If you apply it and it makes your binary image greyscale, you can re-threshold it to make it binary again.

Comment: do you have a software preference? 1) create images with the type of noise you want, 2) add it to your binary image, 3) binarize it again.